# TextView remains the same it doesnt get set to any new value

Tags: android, textview, datainputstream

I'm facing a problem,On a button press i try to read the DataInputstream which has data coming in and display the data.

I'm using a while loop to read the data. But the dynamic update of the Textview doesnt happen.

```
TextView datatextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data); 

DataInputStream Din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Button getData= (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
getData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 
    //.......stuff .......
    try{
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    String message1 = "";
    while (true) {
        message1 = "";
        data = Din.readLine();
        bytesRead = (reading).length();
        if (bytesRead != -1) {
            Log.v(TAG,"data"+data); //I'm getting the data correctly
            //But not able to update it in the TextView :(
            datatextview.setText(data);  //doesnt work
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to exit your method and relinquish control of the UI thread in order for your views to update. You should probably be using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) with its progress updating functionality to do this, so that you're not hogging the UI thread.

Something like:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
  private final TextView progress;

  public MyTask(TextView progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress.setText("Starting...");
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    ... your buffer code, including publishProgress(data); in your while loop ...
  }

  @Override    
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... data) {
    progress.setText(data[0]);
    progress.invalidate(); // not sure if this is necessary or not
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    progress.setText("Finished!");
  }
}
```

Then you can create and execute your AsyncTask using:

```
new MyTask(datatextview).execute();
```

**Edit** - make sure to use `@Override` which helps alert you if your method signatures are not correct.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have my DataStream objects in a different class , and say myTask is a new class , now i hav the problem of accessing those.

Comment: you can transfer the data objects in onPostExecute, or you can use the AsyncTask as an inner class.

Comment: I tried the same , by having my reading stream data in "doInBackground". But the result i got is "starting" . I was continuously getting data in the logcat. But not on the UI(textView). Then once i stopped the device i got finished in textView.
I think the problem is that i'm invoking it from the class like

Class A {

In OnCreate()

onButtonClick  call-> 
 new GetData(readingtextview).execute();

 Class nestedB extends Async{
 
  doInBackground()
  publishProgress()
 
  }
`
 }

Comment: I was trying to say that i'm using the nested class approach,but it didnt work . I'm just getting "Starting" in my TextView

Comment: What if you include @Override on your methods to make sure you are actually overriding them?

Comment: The method should've been `onProgressUpdate`. I gave you the wrong name earlier. Using @Override would've flagged this as an error. Your code should work with the new version.

Comment: Its working great !!! Thank you Matthew. I changed the name to onProgressUpdate and it works without overriding.

Comment: Great. You really should use @Override though. It doesn't change the program, but it does catch your spelling mistakes (like the one I made!)

Comment: Hi Matthew, Is it possible to update to a canvas instead of updating to a textview. I was trying something like , but its not working . Any ideas . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635434/android-text-not-visible-on-writing-using-drawtext

Answer (score 0):

Matthew is right here but to elaborate...

If you are doing this from a thread you are probably stuck looping so fast the UI never gets a chance to redraw with your new values.  If you want to force a redraw of the UI from a thread call [`View.invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29).

If you are doing this from your main thread (which you should definitely reconsider) again you are stuck looping and UI can't redraw...you would want to all [`View.postInvalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) to force a UI redraw.